# What can be done to bridge the Air Gap, except autorun?

Tags: hardware, physical, hardening, air-gap

What can be done to bridge the [Air Gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_%28networking%29), except [autorun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun)?

Is there any hardware butterflies that can attack physically isolated Unix/Linux machine in common usb drives, like VSC (Vendor Specific Commands)?

http://www.recover.co.il/SA-cover/SA-cover.pdf

Answer (score 13):

Any bug in the handling of USB devices can be exploited by malicious hardware. That's how the [PS3 Jailbreak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_Jailbreak) worked.

Remember that when you plug a "USB Flash drive" in a machine, you cannot be sure that what you plug is really "just a Flash drive". The machine sees it as a "USB *device*" which may claim to be a keyboard, a mouse, a network interface... A malicious Flash drive could be in fact a wireless network device, which claims to be some sort of ethernet card; the machine may react by automatically connecting to it (DHCP and so on): no more air gap !

Alternatively, the USB device may claim to be a [USB-to-firewire converter](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41682/usb-to-firewire-converter-is-a-security-issue/41730#41730) and the device driver, already known to the machine, would then grant device-initiated [DMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) privileges: the device can then read and write any data byte in the machine.

Really, if you are serious about your security, don't plug untrusted device in a USB port.

Comment: Did you mean that better use CD/DVD disc?

Comment: Indeed, a CD would be better, since a CD-ROM reader won't use it in any way other than reading bytes. A CD won't be able to masquerade as another kind of device. As you have noticed, beware of any Autorun features, of course.

Comment: Great, I'll not put you answer as completed, but anyway thank you very much. Still waiting for more informative instructions to bridge air gap.

Comment: See, Schneier builds his own air gap. Comments are pretty. https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2013/10/air_gaps.html