# How to detect if a system is infected by key logger or not?

Tags: keyloggers

Assume that you want to login your Gmail account on your friend's laptop and you are doubt if he installed a keylogger on his computer. How you can be sure if there is any key logger installed or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defence Against Keyboard Keylogger](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44268/defence-against-keyboard-keylogger)

Comment: Not really @Ulkoma. The question is different since they were talking about physical keyloggers whereas here the question broader.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would require too much effort and still you would not be 100% sure.

- Have a reliable anti malware with the latest update perform a deep scan to look for it.
- If you are very well experience with the OS' processes, take a look to see if any unknown process is currently running.
- Check the connected USB devices to the computer. Two keyboards are a indication

What could help you:

- Use a system virtual keyboard to type in your password.

Comment: A virtual keyboard can still be detected.